# @Entity Relation between tables on different databases

Tags: jpa, netbeans, entity, eclipselink, one-to-one

I'm new on Java Enterprise and JPA (Using EclipseLink JPA 2.0 from Netbeans).
I'm trying to realize a link between different @Entity classes in different projects and packages, with no success.

Database D1 has a table T1 and a Synonym T2 referencing table T2 on Database D2.

So I create 2 projects(Jars):

D1-jpa containing @Entity package1.T1.class and persistence.xml (mapping also T2)

D2-jpa containing @Entity package1.T2.class and persistence.xml

I need to create a @OneToOne relation from T1 to T2 so that T1 has

@OneToOne

public T2 t2;

The problem is when I try to execute the simple JPQL query:

SELECT t FROM T1 t

The translated query is something like

SELECT t.field1, t.field2 , T2_t2 FROM T1 t; -- "T2_t2"??

when I expected something as
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.field1 FROM T1 t1, T2 t2

WHERE (join condition)

What's your solutions to the problem? What if synonym on D1 has different names from the real Table on D2 (Synonym TT2 referencing T2 on D2 ...)?

Regard all.

F.

Comment: "With composite persistence units:

Mapping relationships can be established among any of the entities in the composite."
This looks great, but it's the same (as performace for example) as join tables using synonyms from one db to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@OneToOne in pure JPA only works if the target is an entity within this persistence unit.  Since you are not getting exceptions, then it is working as if both are can be found and processed by the D1 persistence unit classloader.  The mapping is defaulting the T1->T2 foreign key field to "T2_t2" probably because your T2 entity has t2 field or property marked as its ID.  You will need to specify the join column on the relationship if you want a different database column to be used as the foreign key.

I'm not clear on your purpose, since T1 must be able to import T2, so they are not completely separate - the tables should be in the same database as well for there to be a 1:1 between them.  But you can accomplish bringing together multiple persistence units and using them as one with the composite persistence unit feature in EclipseLink described here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Composite_Persistence_Units

Comment: You're right It's in fact a ManyToOne relation (D1 is a Database containg people and D2 one containing Doctors, a person has one Doctor, Doctor many people) I changed it to OneToOne to simplify the example but I was wrong.
Maybe in the real code a OneToOne relation does not work as you said.
I'll watch the link provided, Thanks.
Regards.